# ui-select2 - Make adding a new tag appear at the bottom of the list

Tags: ui-select2

The default in ui-select2 when adding a new tag makes the current text option appear on top of the drop-down list.

For example, if I wish to type "English," an item that exists in my list of options, as I type "Eng," the auto-suggested text "English" appears second on the drop-down list, while "Eng" appears first (i.e. add a new tag "Eng" instead of picking the existing option "English").

This is a little problematic if I wanted to type "Eng" and hit enter to get the recommended option "English," but I would like to have the option of creating my own tag that is not in the list of existing options. The best solution for this that I can think of is to put the currently-typed text option ("Eng") move to the bottom, and have the list of recommended options (in this case "English") appear first.

Is there any way to do this in ui-select2? I tried using createSearchChoicePosition as follows just to try it out:

```
createSearchChoice: function(term) { return {id: 3,text:term}; },
createSearchChoicePosition: 'top'
```

But it didn't affect anything (even when I change the position to 'bottom'). Is there any other way to do this or am I using createSearchChoicePosition incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a possible solution:

```
    $('.select2field').select2({
        tags: null,
        createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
            console.log('createSearchChoice');
            console.log(data);
            return {
                id: -1,
                text: term,
                isNew: true
            };
        },
        createSearchChoicePosition: 'bottom',
        width: '300px',
        query: function (options) {
            console.log('query');
            options.context = options.context || {
            };
            if (options.page === 1 )
            {
                var result = {
                    results: [
                        {id: 0, text: 'English'},
                        {id: 1, text: 'Spanish'},
                        {id: 2, text: 'Chinese'}
                    ],
                    more: true
                };
                options.callback(result);
            }
            else if (options.page === 2)
            {
                var result = {
                    results: [
                        {id: 3, text: 'French'},
                        {id: 4, text: 'German'},
                        {id: 5, text: 'Portugese'}
                    ],
                    more: false
                };
                options.context.page = 2
                options.callback(result);
            }
        }
    })
    .on('select2-loaded', function(items) { 
        console.log('select2-loaded');
        console.log(items);
    })
    .on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
        if (e.object.isNew) {
            alert("Is new!");
        }
    });
```

And this is the jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Jpq/5/)

As you can see, the results are returned to the select2 control through the "query" function, and it emulates an ajax call.
It puts the new element at the bottom of the first page (between Chinese and French). This is the normal behaviour of the CreateSearchChoicePosition.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that response. I've tried it out and it looks like it works fine in your JSFiddle. The key being that "createSearchChoicePosition: 'bottom'" behaves as expected. I am using the AngularJS version of select2, and it looks like the createSearchChoicePosition in angular's ui-select2 is always "top," even when I specify it to be "bottom." I used the exact same code you provided and it didn't work. I'll submit a request to those guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not trying to be pedantic by suggesting this (because I've been suffering from the same issue you've described), but have you checked the version of select2 you are referencing?

In my case I had inadvertently made reference to v3.4.5: using any version newer than this solves the problem for me.

This can be demonstrated using soycabanillas' JSFiddle example by downgrading his external resources from 3.4.6.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Semantics. The clarifying question is rhetorical, the answer then follows.